# How to add a new Inspector(apart from the Inspector of elements and links) in jointJS - Rappid

Tags: javascript, jointjs, inspector, rappid

I want to add a 3rd Inspector which will open only for an element(not a link) of specific type, for example only for basic.Rect in Rappid.

So far, there are 2 Inspectors.For elements and for links.

Is there any way it can be done?

The following code is a part of the KitchenSkink version of Rappid.

Here is function **createInspector:**

```
createInspector: function(cellView) {

    var cell = cellView.model || cellView;

    // No need to re-render inspector if the cellView didn't change.
    if (!this.inspector || this.inspector.options.cell !== cell) {

        // Is there an inspector that has not been removed yet.
        // Note that an inspector can be also removed when the underlying cell is removed.
        if (this.inspector && this.inspector.el.parentNode) {

            this.inspectorClosedGroups[this.inspector.options.cell.id] = _.map(app.inspector.$('.group.closed'), function(g) {
        return $(g).attr('data-name');
    });

            // Clean up the old inspector if there was one.
            this.inspector.updateCell();
            this.inspector.remove();
        }

        var inspectorDefs = InspectorDefs[cell.get('type')];

        this.inspector = new joint.ui.Inspector({
            inputs: inspectorDefs ? inspectorDefs.inputs : CommonInspectorInputs,
            groups: inspectorDefs ? inspectorDefs.groups : CommonInspectorGroups,
            cell: cell
        });

        this.initializeInspectorTooltips();

        this.inspector.render();
        $('.inspector-container').html(this.inspector.el);

        if (this.inspectorClosedGroups[cell.id]) {

    _.each(this.inspectorClosedGroups[cell.id], this.inspector.closeGroup, this.inspector);

        } else {
            this.inspector.$('.group:not(:first-child)').addClass('closed');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way it can be done?

Comment: I am not I understand this question properly. How about adding the  `basic.Rect` inspector definition to your `InspectorDefs` object.

Comment: Roman I don't understand what code should I write inside function createInspector to open a new inspector for this specific element, let's say basic.Rect. I want to have a 3rd inspector with different inspecttor fields, specially defined for this basic.Rect

Answer (score 1):

If you use [`joint.ui.Inspector.create('#path', inspectorProperties)`](https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/rappid/v2.2/ui.html#ui.Inspector.create) any previous instance of the Inspector in a specific DOM element is removed and new one is created and rendered into the DOM automatically (it avoids creating a new instance of `joint.ui.Inspector()`, rendering it, adding the rendered result manually and removing the previous instance).

> It also keeps track on open/closed groups and restore them based on the last used state.

Besides this, you may always have several different `inspectorProperties` objects previously defined when you are about to `create()` the inspector. So following the code you pasted, you could perform the tests you need first and then create the appropriate inspector:

```
if(cell instanceof joint.basic.Rect){

  var customInputs = _.clone(CommonInspectorInputs);
  // extend more inputs into `customInputs` from a variable previously defined
  // OR modify the default rectangle's inspector directly, example:
  customInputs.attrs.text = {
    type: 'textarea',
    label: 'Multiline text',
    text: 'Type\nhere!',
    group: joint.util.getByPath(CommonInspectorInputs.attrs, 'text/group', '/');
  };

  joint.ui.Inspector.create('.extra-inspector-container', {
    cell: cell
    inputs: customInputs,
    groups: CommonInspectorGroups,
  });
} // if only ONE inspector needs to be loaded add an ELSE block here
  // and use '.inspector-container' in the `create()` above

// If `InspectorDefs` is a global variable with all the cells inspectors properties
// create and load the default inspector
joint.ui.Inspector.create('.inspector-container', _.extend({cell: cell},
  InspectorDefs[cell.get('type')])
);
```